# Symfony 2.1 Security Cross Subdomain

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

Running Symfony 2.1 on an application and we have different sandboxes of the code. Eg.

- `aequasi.someurl.com`
- `dev.someurl.com`
- `hotcarl.someurl.com`

I cant seem to figure out why, but when im logged into `aequasi`, and i go to `hotcarl`, i need to log in again. When i do, it logs me out of `aequasi`.

All sandboxes are using the same database for auth

i have this in my `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: .someurl.com
        domain:        .someurl.com
```

ive got the `php.ini` set up to use the same url too

also, the session_id's are the same

Comment: Are the security firewalls on all 3 sites named the same thing?

Comment: three three branches of code are completely identical, at the moment. Only thing that differs, is the url

Comment: What happens when you point all three domains to the same sandbox? Does this still occure? As per default, symfony is saving the session information inside the cache directory, so if you access a different sandbox, the session information are again sent (I guess) but the new sandbox cannot find them in it's own cache directory, so you have to log in again.

Comment: Is there a way to change that functionality?

Comment: Both pointed to the same directory and this is still occuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a database, or memory as the Session storage. This allows you to share session data across three different symfony applications (each with their own sandbox). This will remove the inconsistencies between application caches and allow you to use a *.domain.com type cookie.

Symfony2 provides several drivers for alternative session storage.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#custom-save-handlers

Comment: where is this logic supposed to go?

Comment: well, did some research, wasnt very easy to find, but i used this
http://hipaway.com/blog/symfony2-sessions-in-memcache/

Comment: Little out of date tho, i think im gonna make my own blog post and updating the solution a bit. Thanks for your help james!